# CloudFormation Circular Dependency Between Route53, Certificate Manager & CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, aws-certificate-manager

The following code is my attempt at creating a SPA (Single Page Application) CloudFormation template. I understand there are probably many flaws but I can't conceptually understand how to break the circular dependency error I am getting. In my head, it only makes sense that Route53 depends on CloudFront because it needs to know the `AliasTarget`, it also makes sense that CloudFront needs to depend on Certificate Manager because it needs `AcmCertificateArn` and CertificateManager needs to depend on Route53 (for obvious reasons but I have a feeling someone is going to tell me this is where I break the chain).

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Creates an S3 bucket configured for hosting a static website, and a Route
  53 DNS record pointing to the bucket
Parameters:
  DomainName:
    Type: String
    Description: The DNS name of an existing Amazon Route 53 hosted zone e.g. jevsejev.io
    AllowedPattern: (?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-.]{1,63}(?<!-)
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid DNS zone name.
  FullDomainName:
    Type: String
    Description: The full domain name e.g. development.jevsejev.io
    AllowedPattern: (?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-.]{1,63}(?<!-)
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid DNS zone name.
Resources:
  Route53:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
    DependsOn:
      - Cloudfront
    Properties:
      HostedZoneName: !Ref 'DomainName'
      RecordSets:
        Name: !Ref 'FullDomainName'
        Type: A
        AliasTarget: 
          DNSName: !GetAtt [Cloudfront, WebsiteURL]
  CertificateManager:
    Type: AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate
    DependsOn:
      - Route53
    Properties:
      DomainName: !Ref 'FullDomainName'
  Cloudfront:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    DependsOn:
    - S3
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Origins:
        - DomainName: !GetAtt [S3, WebsiteURL]
          Id: S3Origin
          CustomOriginConfig:
            HTTPPort: '80'
            HTTPSPort: '443'
            OriginProtocolPolicy: http-only
        Enabled: true
        HttpVersion: 'http2'
        DefaultRootObject: index.html
        Aliases:
        - !Ref 'FullDomainName'
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          AllowedMethods:
          - GET
          - HEAD
          Compress: true
          TargetOriginId: S3Origin
          ForwardedValues:
            QueryString: true
            Cookies:
              Forward: none
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
        PriceClass: PriceClass_All
        ViewerCertificate:
          AcmCertificateArn: !Ref CertificateManager
          SslSupportMethod: sni-only
  S3:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref 'FullDomainName'
      AccessControl: PublicRead
      WebsiteConfiguration:
        IndexDocument: index.html
```

Comment: Certificate manager does not depend on Route 53. It just needs a template parameter.

Comment: So ignoring CloudFormation, if I wanted to create a Certificate for a subdomain that I have not created with Route53 that would be fine?

Comment: Yes, you can create certificates for custom domains as long as you can prove domain ownership via email or DNS records.

Answer (score 2):

I also have this problem and just get fixed.
Hope this it's helpful for people

The `Certificate` part once you have this property `DomainValidationOptions` and use `your own HostedZone Id` as Value of `HostedZoneId`, Certificate will get created without hanging there.

Below are my code for reference:

`CldoudFrontHostedZoneId` is a fixed value from AWS documents
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-aliastarget.html

`DefaultHostedZoneId` is my HostedZone Id

```
Parameters:

  DefaultHostedZoneId:
    Description: Default own HostedZone Id
    Type: String
    Default: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

  CldoudFrontHostedZoneId:
    Description: AWS only use this hosted zone Id for cloudfront
    Type: String
    Default: Z2FDTNDATAQYW2
```

```
Resources:
  StagingCloudFrontCertificate:
    Type: AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate
    Properties:
      DomainName: yyyyy.xxxxxxxx.company.com
      ValidationMethod: DNS
      DomainValidationOptions:
        - DomainName: yyyyy.xxxxxxxx.company.com
          HostedZoneId: !Ref DefaultHostedZoneId

StagingCloudFrontDistribution:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Origins:
        - DomainName: !GetAtt StagingPublishedS3.DomainName
          Id: !Ref StagingPublishedS3
          S3OriginConfig:
            OriginAccessIdentity: !Join ['', ['origin-access-identity/cloudfront/', !Ref StagingCloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity]]
        Enabled: 'true'
        Comment: Staging CloudFront Distribution
        HttpVersion: http2
        IPV6Enabled: true
        PriceClass: PriceClass_100
        Aliases: 
        - yyyyy.xxxxxxxx.company.com
        ViewerCertificate:
          MinimumProtocolVersion: TLSv1.2_2021
          AcmCertificateArn: !Ref StagingCloudFrontCertificate           
          SslSupportMethod: sni-only
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          AllowedMethods:
            - GET
            - HEAD
            - OPTIONS
          CachePolicyId: !Ref AWSmanagedCachePolicy
          # ForwardedValues:
          #   QueryString: false
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: 'redirect-to-https'
          TargetOriginId: !Ref StagingPublishedS3
          TrustedKeyGroups:
          - !Ref StagingCloudFrontKeyGroup
        CacheBehaviors:
          - AllowedMethods:
            - GET
            - HEAD
            PathPattern: /favicon.ico
            TargetOriginId: !Ref StagingPublishedS3
            ViewerProtocolPolicy: 'redirect-to-https'
            CachePolicyId: !Ref AWSmanagedCachePolicy
        
  StagingCloudfrontDNS:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
    Properties:
      HostedZoneName: xxxxxxxx.company.com.
      Comment: Zone apex alias targeted to CloudFront
      RecordSets:
      - Name: yyyyy.xxxxxxxx.company.com.
        Type: A
        AliasTarget:
          HostedZoneId: !Ref CldoudFrontHostedZoneId
          DNSName: !GetAtt StagingCloudFrontDistribution.DomainName
      - Name: yyyyy.xxxxxxxx.company.com.
        Type: AAAA
        AliasTarget:
          HostedZoneId: !Ref CldoudFrontHostedZoneId
          DNSName: !GetAtt StagingCloudFrontDistribution.DomainName
```